# Is there a way to showcase the differences between two versions of the same file in PowerBI?

Tags: csv, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Let's say that on a daily basis I download a CSV file and I would like to show in the dashboard the differences between the two versions of the same file(today and the day before) in the dashboard such as for example, the number of new rows added to that file(these could be defined as new cases), or the number of cells that were changed from one category to another, such as 'Still Ill' to 'Recovered'.

Is this possible to achieve through a DAX Expression or through a specific transformation that is done on import? Or should I somehow append the csv data to the original one and PowerBI would remove the duplicates?

I've attempted to solve the problem through the following three questions but somehow couldn't find the answer I needed there:

[Detect differences between two versions of the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25143121/detect-differences-between-two-versions-of-the-same-table)

[Python: Match values between two csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899160/python-match-values-between-two-csv-files)

[Issue computing difference between two csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50263129/issue-computing-difference-between-two-csv-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible if you load in both versions of the CSV file into the same PBIX.

Otherwise, the answer is Power BI is [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58347703) [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60531079) [database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60948771).