# Is there a way to detect new input and change their status every month in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm trying to make a rows that detect "new ID" that's coming every month into the database and will put it as a "Existent ID" at the start of a new month is it possible ?

What I want to achieve :

[image]

Currently trying to do it in PowerQuery or DAX ...

Thank you all for the help !

Comment: I don't think Power BI is the right tool for this. Similar questions are linked to in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61900494).

Answer (score 1):

If the requirement is to mark as "New ID" the IDs that didn't exist in the previous month, and "Existent ID" otherwise, then we might add a calculated column. Since calculated columns are evaluated during the data refresh, it's possible to use use the TODAY() function to read the current date and use it to check the first appearence date for the current ID.
The code might be something like the following

```
Type =
VAR CurrentDate =
    TODAY()
VAR CurrentYear =
    YEAR( CurrentDate )
VAR CurrentMonth =
    MONTH( CurrentDate )
VAR CurrentId = MyTable[ID]
VAR FirstOccurrenceOfID =
    CALCULATE(
        MIN( MyTable[Date] ),
        MyTable[ID] = CurrentID
    )
VAR FirstOccurrenceOfIDYear =
    YEAR( FirstOccurrenceOfID )
VAR FirstOccurrenceOfIDMonth =
    MONTH( FirstOccurrenceOfID )
VAR Result =
    IF(
        CurrentYear = FirstOccurrenceOfIDYear
            && CurrentMonth = FirstOccurrenceOfIDMonth,
        "New ID",
        "Existent ID"
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

If instead the requirement is to detect the lines that where added since the previous refresh, I'm afraid that with standard refresh it's not possible.
(Acutally I don't know if the [incremental refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-premium-incremental-refresh) allows to see what are the records that are added, but it's purpose is to cut the refresh time so I suppose it doesn't)

Comment: Hey !

Firstly thank you so much for you help, I finally have something that I can work with ! 

And may I ask your help a bit more, is it also possible to detect the "old" new Id on the previous month ?  

Thank you so much again for the help !

Comment: So the rule based on the current month and not on the difference between refreshes could do? For the  question about the previous new ids, I suppose it could be possible to implement a rule to check if the ID appeared for the first time in the previous month. But it would be a different question: would it be a new calculated column? or a third state? Maye you could post a new question with a precise description of what should be the desired result. :)

Comment: I just answered my own question, really don't know how to use stack haha

Comment: From the answer you posted here with the stacked column chart I understood that what you really need is to get the number of new IDs per month. This can be implemented with a measure that uses the currently selected month instead of  a calculated column.